# How to run Go program as a service

Tags: windows, go, service

I try to use https://github.com/kardianos/service library  but can't manage to get it to work.

I have the following code :

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/kardianos/service"
    "github.com/reujab/wallpaper"
)

var logger service.Logger

type program struct{}

func (p *program) Start(s service.Service) error {
    // Start should not block. Do the actual work async.
    go p.run()
    return nil
}
func (p *program) run() {
    // link to whaterver image from the web
    wallpaper.SetFromURL("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1910/MilkyWaySaltFlat_Huerta_960_annotated.jpg")
}
func (p *program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
    // Stop should not block. Return with a few seconds.
    return nil
}

    func main() {
        svcConfig := &service.Config{
            Name:        "GoServiceExampleSimple",
            DisplayName: "Go Service Example",
            Description: "This is an example Go service.",
        }

        prg := &program{}
        s, err := service.New(prg, svcConfig)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        logger, err = s.Logger(nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = s.Run()
        if err != nil {
            logger.Error(err)
        }
    }
```

When I run the program itself, the call to `wallpaper.SetFromURL()` works well, but I got no services registered afterward.

What am I missing? I seems everyone uses this solution very simply and I feel even dumber.

Comment: Looks lik eyou're not running `Service.Install` to actually install the service? https://godoc.org/github.com/kardianos/service#Service